# sheet.deleteRows() - Need to delete all the rows with data from top (preferably from 2nd row)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, delete-row

I need to delete 200-300 rows, excluding row 1.  The script below is getting an out of bounds error, and it's slow. Can someone help with a way to speed up the process?

** IF POSSIBLE EXCLUDE ROW_1

```
function clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('test');

  var start=1;
  var end=300;
  for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) 
    { sheet.deleteRow(i); }

}
```

[SAMPLE SHEET -  TAKE COPY](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wKIdOGg1Hw9EAlVrMyYaKuUaWOksW8_nwUH7_XPHruc/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 44):

Don't use a `for` loop.  You can delete multiple rows in a Google Spreadsheet in one operation:

```
var start, howManyToDelete;

start = 2;//Hard coded row number from where to start deleting

howManyToDelete = sheet.getLastRow() - start + 1;//How many rows to delete -
      //The blank rows after the last row with content will not be deleted

sheet.deleteRows(start, howManyToDelete);
```

If you wanted to delete from row 2 to row 10, that is 9 rows to delete.  The number of rows to delete must be 9.  Only row 1 will be left after deleting row 2 to 10.

[Apps Script Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRows(Integer,Integer))

Comment: This is the correct way of doing it. The documentation specifies that you should use as few calls to edit the function as possible. Another example would be writing data to a spreadsheet. Instead of using a loop to output data to the spreadsheet, you should instead output everything to an array and then write the array to the spreadsheet.

Comment: This should probably consume the `start` variable in determining the count to be deleted. Link is dead too, should be https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany

Answer (score 7):

FYI: getLastRow() returns the index of the last row WITH content. Use getMaxRows() to return the absolute last row (regardless of content).

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Be aware when using the answer by Alan Wells!</strike> (Edit: he has corrected his answer.)

`getLastRow()` returns the ***index*** of the last row with content.

But, the second parameter in `deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)` is ***count of rows to be deleted***, and not index of the last row.

Therefore, to delete all non-blank rows after a specific row, you would have to do:

```
function deleteAllBelow(startFrom)
{
    // get last row index
    var lastRowWithContent = sheet.getLastRow();

    if(lastRowWithContent < startFrom)
    {
        // rows below startFrom are already blank!
        return;
    }
    
    // count total number of rows to be deleted
    // +1 is to include the last row
    var totalRowsToBeDeleted = lastRowWithContent - startFrom + 1;
    
    sheet.deleteRows(startFrom, totalRowsToBeDeleted); 
}
```

Suppose that the last row with content is 20.

Now `deleteAllBelow(15);` will delete all non-blank rows from 15 to 20, and `totalRowsToBeDeleted` will be 6 (because 15 and 20 *are both included*).

This also takes care of cases when there is no non-blank rows at or below your starting row.

Answer (score 0):

heey,

if someone wants to delete rows but without deleting the formating of them you can use method clearContent() instead of deleteRows(), you have to use getRange() though

```
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(); 
sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),3).clearContent();
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to delete all the rows you can use clear function.

```
// This example assumes there is a sheet named "first"
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var first = ss.getSheetByName("first");
first.clear();
```

[App Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#clear())

Comment: Clear doesn't delete the rows, it just delete row contents and attributes like data validation, notes, etc.