# Select Rows in Loop

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I`d like to make a function clear:

```
 function clear() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    for(var i=2;i<1001;i++) {
     if (spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(i,2).getValue() == "a") {
      spreadsheet.getRange(i:i).activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows());
}
}
}
```

but i have problem with this line:

```
spreadsheet.getRange(i:i).activate()
```

How shout I write this to select row number 'i'?

Comment: I also try to do this like:
  `z='"' + i + ':' + i + '"'   
  spreadsheet.getRange(z).activate();
  `
but I have an information that Range not found

Comment: ``i+':'+i``. Also note that, that line is not needed. `deleteRow(i,1)` should be enough.

Comment: Why are you even trying to activate a `Range`? You almost never need to do that--just programmatically manipulate it without the meaningless fluff of `activate` -> `getActiveRange`

Comment: Welcome. Have a look at `getDataRange`. The [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) for `getDataRange` has an excellent, **short**, working example of how to loop though every row **and** column. Even though you don't want to loop the columns, it is worth running the script as-is just to see how the looping works and to distinguish the row and column components; then you can just remove the column part.

Answer (score 0):

> How shout I write this to select row number 'i'?

Instead of `i:i` use `i+':'+i`

REMARKS:

1. The code in the question is very inefficient for deleting rows. It's possible to delete several rows at a time by using `deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)`.

Related

- [sheet.deleteRows() Need to delete all the rows with data from top (preferably 2nd row)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37577200/1595451)
- [Deleting rows in google sheets using Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37924842/1595451)