# Delete ALL Rows from a GSheet (empty and not empty)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I delete ALL rows in a google sheet using a script. The sheet.deleteRows() formula assumes I know the number of rows.

[image]

As shown in this example, the table is already sorted and I can delete all rows from the last table row (CTRL+DOWN).
I can't use the For...Next loop, otherwise I'll run into the GScript timeout.

Is there a command that can jump directly to the last line to determine the number?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related question: [sheet.deleteRows() - Need to delete all the rows with data from top (preferably from 2nd row)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37577658/1330560). Several answers to choose from.

Comment: sheet.deleteRows(1,sh.getLastRow())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your particular example you could use the following code as a reference:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Change the name to the one you have in your Spreadsheet
  var dataRange = ss.getRange("A1:B4");
  ss.deleteRows(dataRange.getLastRow()+1, ss.getMaxRows()-ss.getLastRow());
  ss.deleteColumns(dataRange.getLastColumn()+1, ss.getMaxColumns()-ss.getLastColumn());

}
```

#### References:

- [getLastColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastcolumn)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [getMaxColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns)
- [getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)

Comment: Wowwww - so complex and so easy - many many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need to clear data, re-consider your approach. Maybe clearing instead of deleting would be enough for you.

Another thing, you can use [getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) method to select "everything" on the sheet.

For example:

```
sheet.getDataRange().clear();
sheet.getDataRange().clearContent();
```